# How to do normal build instead of Super Dev with gradle?

Tags: java, gwt, gradle, libgdx

I'm trying to make a html build with gradle on my libgdx project. I use the the Gradle menu to type command `dist`. After 1-2 minutes the build is finished ok and I copy the resulting files on a webserver.

The problem is I always get a "Super Dev" refresh button. I guess this means it is not a normal build but a Super Dev. As I understand it, superdev is slower and should be used only in developement enviroment not a production one.

So how to make a normal build?

Comment: What gradle plugin is being used here?

Comment: I checked Eclipse Instalation Details and I have "Gradle IDE" version 3.6.4.201412092323-CI-B19.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear. I meant, what plugin(s) are being applied in your build.gradle file?

Comment: project html has: <<apply plugin: "gwt">> and <<apply plugin: "war">>

Comment: I don't know libgdx' build process, but everything that is being built with gradle supports running `gradle tasks` from the commandline. That should show all (the important) things you can do in your project. Maybe there is something other than `dist`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the build was not a superdev after all.

LibGdx just inserts the "SuperDev" button but it doesn't have any functionality behind it.